# Offering discounted/dynamic IAP pricing for items on app stores (using flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, playback

I have an app built in flutter, with IAP in both google and ios playstore. I am looking for a way to offer a dynamic price for IAP, based on other purchases/sales.

Consider the following structure:

- 10 unique items at $1.99 each

  - `Buy for 1.99 each`
  - `Buy all 10 for $19.90`
  - If 1 item has been purchased, `Buy remaining for $17.91` ($19.90 - $1.99)

Creating all of the possibilities for all of the prices for these 10 episodes would require 10 items in the app store. However, Apple doesn't offer the ability to create an item for `$17.91`. My initial thought was to calculate the price and round down to the nearest available IAP, but this solution still requires creating numerous IAP and sometimes gives the user a large discount. (The pricing in apple is not consistent).

Given that I want flexibility on pricing (especially if running a sale) and there are a ton of different price points, depending on the individual item pricing, what are my options for accomplishing the above predicament?

**Is it possible to create items with unique prices in the app store dynamically?**

Note: Apple TV has somehow done this on their app, as you can purchase items at prices that are not offered in app store connect.

Comment: usually this type of disscount is set trhoug the app store directly, either on appstore connect or googleplay, in there you can define various behaviors for the diferent purchase elements you may have